# Generate series of emails with VBA causing Run-time error '91'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm trying to create a macro that loops through a list of email addresses in a range and if the value does not equal #N/A then it creates a standard templated email. As the list will change over time I have allowed for the user to add a row number to cell 'B1' to make the range count dynamic.

The above works fine but for some reason it keeps giving me Run-time error '91' message when I try to run it which is suggesting and issue in my loop.

The code is below and I have commented the line where the error appears.

As always, help is appreciated.

```
Sub generateEmail()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim endNum As Long

'Set the last row number in range for loop to look through
endNum = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B" & endNum)

'Loop through range and if cell value equals #N/A then skip and move on to next one
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value <> "#N/A" Then '<< ERROR HIGHLIGHTED ON THIS LINE
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Test Email"
            '.Body = " "
            .Display
        End With
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I used cell and c to do the same thing. I only needed one of those variables, however, it trips up on the #N/A filter piece of the code.

Here's my revised code:

```
Sub generateEmail()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set variables
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim endNum As Long

'Set Outlook App
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Set the last row number in range for loop to look through
endNum = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B" & endNum)

'Loop through range and if cell value equals #N/A then skip and move on to next one
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value <> "#N/A" Then '<< ERROR HIGHLIGHTED ON THIS LINE
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .To = c.Value
            .Subject = "Test Email"
            '.Body = " "
            .Display
        End With
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It is probably a good idea to use the "Edit" option and update your question.

Comment: Apologies, still working out how to use this site. Will do going forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write `If Not IsError(c) Then` instead of `If c.Value <> "#N/A" Then`.

Answer (score 0):

try below line instead your error line

```
c.Value<>CVErr(xlErrNA)
```